# Retrieve location data from GMB API using Service Accounts in 2020

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-my-business-api

I want to fetch my GMB data daily with a cronjob.

The [GMB API documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/oauth-setup) only explains how to get the Access Token with the standard Oauth setup. It doesn't work for applications like this, without any frontend, because the Consent Screen.

It's possible to skip the Consent Screen using Service Accounts, but not all the Google APIs support this method.

There are a lot of [posts](https://support.google.com/business/thread/8281160?hl=en) talking about the same problem.

**Questions:**

- **Do the GMB API supports Oauth via Service Accounts in 2020?**
- If the answer is yes, is there any official documentation? (I've spend a lot of time on research with no results).
- If the answer is not, is it possible to generate Access Token with no expirations? Or a long time duration token at least...

Comment: - **Did you check the documentation**  If Yes what did you find.  If not why don't you try? Listing what your research has found so far.   If something is not documented thats normally a big clue that its not supported.   Access tokens by their nature are short lived and will only work for one hower there is nothing you can do about that Have you considered saving the refresh token and using that to request a new access token

Comment: Google doesn't confirm explicitly if it's possible to make request to GMB API but it's not so clear in the official document! Using HTTP Request directly works but not for GMB! My requests returns 404 Not Found with no extra details: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#making-http-requests-directly

That's why I need to know if GMB API and Service Accounts are compatible for authentication.